# How to show error mark beside SWT widgets?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

On a project based on eclipse RCP:

1. Using SWT and eclipse RCP I want to show error or info mark exactly the same as the following pictures. When the mouse pointer hovers the error mark, a popup shows the reason. I need this capability to show errors or warnings to the user. 
   [image]

   [image]
2. It would be very nice to simultaneously have the same error in the problems view.
   [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You need `ControlDecoration`s (code taken from https://krishnanmohan.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/inline-validations-in-eclipse-rcp-field-assists/):

```
Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
label.setText("Please Enter Pincode:");
label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));

Text txtPincode = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
txtPincode.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));

//Adding the decorator
final ControlDecoration txtDecorator = new ControlDecoration(txtPincode, SWT.TOP|SWT.RIGHT);
FieldDecoration fieldDecoration = FieldDecorationRegistry.getDefault().getFieldDecoration(FieldDecorationRegistry .DEC_ERROR);
Image img = fieldDecoration.getImage();
txtDecorator.setImage(img);
txtDecorator.setDescriptionText("Pls enter only numeric fields");
// hiding it initially
txtDecorator.hide();

txtPincode.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        Text text = (Text)e.getSource();            
        String string = text.getText();
        char[] chars = new char[string.length()];
        string.getChars(0, chars.length, chars, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (!('0' <= chars[i] && chars[i] <= '9')) {
                txtDecorator.show();
            } else {
                txtDecorator.hide();
            }
        }      
    }
});
```

Obviously, you can use `ModifyListener` or `VerifyListener` instead of `KeyListener`. However, doing this manually for every field will result in a lot of unpleasant-to-maintain code. Surprisingly, SWT/JFace doesn't have a good built-in solution for validation, unless you are using data binding (as described in http://www.toedter.com/blog/?p=36). You could write your own small framework to simplify usage.

2) You need to use Markers, e.g.

```
IResource resource = ... // get your specific IResource

resource.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, message);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
```

Don't forget to remove the marker when the field is validated correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved the day for me